# two divided limits

Tags: limits

What is the result of this expression:

$\frac{\lim\limits_{x \to 0}x}{\lim\limits_{x \to 0}x} $

Can I join the two limits to be:

$\frac{\lim\limits_{x \to 0}x}{\lim\limits_{x \to 0}x} =\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{x} = 1$

or it's $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: $0/0$ does not exist, as well as the "result of this expression", which is $0/0$ indeed. So it has no meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of limits is that if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ exists *and* is not equal to $0$ then $$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ exists. This means you may run into some problems depending on how you view your limit. It is true that $\lim_{x \to 0} 1 = 1$ , and it is true that $1 = \frac{x}{x}$ for nonzero $x$. But since $\lim_{x \to 0} x = 0$, you are not justified in saying $\frac{\lim_{x\to 0} x}{\lim_{x\to 0} x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{x}$.

Comment: This is misleading and imprecisely stated in regards to relevant details. (or just incorrect)

Comment: @Hurkyl Can you please expand on why you feel that way? Or how you would have stated things in accordance with regard to relevant details? I feel that I sufficiently answered the question that "no, the limits cannot be combined"

Comment: An example of imprecision is $1 = \frac{x}{x}$; if that were true, you could ultimately justify combining the limits (e.g. by first computing the undefined quotient to be 1). An example of being misleading is that $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ does exists in this problem, so you are partially stating the rule in a way that casts doubt on something that is actually true and doesn't reference the aspects of the rule actually relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to a}g(x)}\iff\exists\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}, \exists\lim_{x\to a}f(x), \exists\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\ne0$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}x=0\therefore\frac{\lim_{x\to0}x}{\lim_{x\to0}x}\ne\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

No. The first expression is undefined. You cannot divide by $0$.